# How to find out LogicApp Http Trigger URL while deploying to new resource group

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I have a situation :

1. Developing and Deploying the HttpTrigger based logicApp using visual Studio
2. Deploying to resource group changes the URL
3. Need to find out the URL to use as a webhook in service bus event

The webhook looks as follows

[image]

If I redeploy without deleting the logicapp it retains the previous URL
[image]

But when I delete the logic app and deploy it generates the new URL

Please guide me how to find the URL of the http trigger so that I can bind it to my service bus webhook. Or is there any way to retain the previous url even if I delete and deploy the logicapp  .

I am doing the delete/deploy/reploy operations in my dev/sit/qas environment , as I am new to logic App so am not sure what step I am missing and if some understanding issue i have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Or is there any way to retain the previous url even if I delete and deploy the logicapp .

**No, it's impossibble.**

When you delete the logic app then deploy or deploy to new resource group, it will create a new logic app. So it will generate a new url.

After you create the endpoint, you can trigger the logic app by sending an HTTPS `POST` request to the endpoint's full URL. Logic apps have built-in support for direct-access endpoints. Please refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-http-endpoint).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an ARM Template when deploying you can use the listCallbackUrl utility (for logic app standard):

```
[listCallbackUrl(resourceId(parameters('resourceGroupName'),'Microsoft.Web/sites/hostruntime/webhooks/api/workflows/triggers', parameters('logicAppName'), 'runtime', 'workflow', 'management', parameters('workflowName'), 'When_a_HTTP_request_is_received'),'2021-03-01').value]
```